# Reading a cell value in Excel vba and write in another Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file and I want to read a value of a cell i.e a cell contains `(S:1 P:0 K:1 Q:1)` I want to read each value and save each value to another column. For example if S:1, then should be another cell 1, how can I read the data from  a cell and write in another cell with macro and vba?

Thank you for your helps

UPDATE:

```
Sub MacroF1()
usedRowCount = Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To usedRowCount
cellAYvalue = Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "AY").Value
If InStr(cellvalue, "S: 1") <> 0 Then
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BC") = 1
Else
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BC") = 0
End If

If InStr(cellvalue, "P: 1") <> 0 Then
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BD") = 1
Else
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BD") = 0
End If

If InStr(cellvalue, "M: 1") <> 0 Then
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BE") = 1
Else
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BE") = 0
End If

If InStr(cellvalue, "L: 1") <> 0 Then
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BF") = 1
Else
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BF") = 0
End If

If InStr(cellvalue, "K: 1") <> 0 Then
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BG") = 1
Else
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BG") = 0
End If

If InStr(cellvalue, "Q: 1") <> 0 Then
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BH") = 1
Else
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BH") = 0
End If
'Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BC") = dd
'Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "AY").Value
'Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Range("BD44") = "Babak"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry .. but what do you mean by **S:1** and other ?

Comment: I mean , that I have a cell with more than one value and I want to process each of them. (S:1 P:0 K:1 Q:1) is in a cell and I want to know if S=1 or not . If yes  I want to write 1 in another cell

Comment: Have you tried : `For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S1:S10").Cells`
        `If condition Then operation`
`Next`
This will allow you to loop through all the cells in the range S1:S10

Comment: I have just updated my code, have you may be better idea to do this job

Comment: @Kaja .. my answer might help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surely you can do this with worksheet formulas, avoiding VBA entirely:

so for this value in say, column AV
    S:1 P:0 K:1 Q:1

you put this formula in column BC:

```
=MID(AV:AV,FIND("S",AV:AV)+2,1)
```

then these formulas in columns BD, BE...

```
=MID(AV:AV,FIND("P",AV:AV)+2,1)
=MID(AV:AV,FIND("K",AV:AV)+2,1)
=MID(AV:AV,FIND("Q",AV:AV)+2,1)
```

so these formulas look for the values **S:1**, **P:1** etc in column AV. If the `FIND` function returns an error, then 0 is returned by the formula, else 1 (like an `IF, THEN, ELSE`

Then you would just copy down the formulas for all the rows in column AV.

HTH
Philip

Comment: thank you for your answer, but may be S: have another number instead of 1 and I want to extract this number i.e S:7 I want to extract 7 and then write 7 in another column

Comment: in that case you would build a formula that searches for the S, then uses MID function to extract the number

Comment: @Kaja: I have updated my code, take a nother loo, or choose an answer that suits you

Answer (score 2):

I have this function for this case ..

```
Function GetValue(r As Range, Tag As String) As Integer
Dim c, nRet As String
Dim n, x As Integer
Dim bNum As Boolean

c = r.Value
n = InStr(c, Tag)
For x = n + 1 To Len(c)
  Select Case Mid(c, x, 1)
    Case ":":    bNum = True
    Case " ": Exit For
    Case Else: If bNum Then nRet = nRet & Mid(c, x, 1)
  End Select
Next
GetValue = val(nRet)
End Function
```

To fill cell BC  .. (assumed that you check cell A1)

```
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BC") = GetValue(range("A1"),"S")
```

Answer (score 1):

The individual alphabets or symbols residing in a single cell can be inserted into different cells in different columns by the following code:

```
For i = 1 To Len(Cells(1, 1))
Cells(2, i) = Mid(Cells(1, 1), i, 1)
Next
```

If you do not want the symbols like colon to be inserted put an if condition in the loop.